# Angular binding to object field

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angular with ng-repeat like that:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(fieldName, fieldValue) in publication">
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-value="publication[fieldName]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

But binding doesn't work - so after change I have still old values in publication[fieldName]. How can I achieve binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `ng-model` instead of `ng-value` if you want a data binding.

Comment: Turn this into answer not a question in answer ... `It should be...`

Comment: done. @GregZuber please accept the answer as correct if you find it correct. :)